# TypeError: this.$backdrop[0] is undefined in bootstrap-lightbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-lightbox

I want to use `bootstrap-lightbox` in my code using [www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox](http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/)

I have tried the following in my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="Lightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class='lightbox-content'>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url().'v_photos/unknown.jpeg';?>">
            <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Your caption here</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#Lightbox">
        <img width="130px" style="border:5px solid #ccc;" src="<?php echo base_url().'v_photos/unknown.jpeg';?>" ></img>
    </a>
</div>
```

and i use `$('#Lightbox').lightbox();` to trigger the lightboxed image!
but I get the bellow error in console:

```
TypeError: this.$backdrop[0] is undefined
```

What am i missing? thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its working in this fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsm5840q/)

```
$('#Lightbox').lightbox();
```

I think you have included js files in wrong order.

It has to be in the following order

1. jQuery
2. Bootstrap
3. Bootstrap Lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Jason Butz's lightbox is no longer maintained and does not work with bootstrap 3 (which you appear to be using), only with bootstrap 2.

Here is a different lightbox script which work's on bootstrap 3: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/